# Symfony 2 locale changing doesnt works

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I am trying to change locale doing the same as in Symfony docs.

My LocaleListener.php

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($locale = $request->query->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }

    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

services.yml

app.locale_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
    arguments: ['%kernel.default_locale%']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

html

```
<li><a href="?_locale=en">{{ 'language.en' | trans }}</a></li>
<li><a href="?_locale=ru">{{ 'language.ru' | trans }}</a></li>
```

I just cant understand why it is not working. Whats wrong here?

EDIT: The locale is changing when i go to another page. What to do, to change it at the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this listener and works for me.
you can change language by passing "lang" param in query string.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;


class LanaguageListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale)
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType())
        {
            return;
        }

        $locale = $request->attributes->get('lang');

        if (!$locale)
        {
            $locale = $request->query->get("lang");
            if (!$locale)
            {
                $locale = $request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale);
            }
        }

        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        $request->setLocale($locale);
        $request->setDefaultLocale($locale);
        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        $request->request->set("lang", $locale);
        $request->query->set("lang", $locale);
//        echo ($locale);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }

}
```